# getting post thumbnail within loop causes an error

Tags: wp-query, post-thumbnails

I have this code that I've been using to pull images from my posts:

```
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

    if (has_post_thumbnail()){
      $nevent .= '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail($post_ID,'full', array( 'class' => 'greenbg' ) ).'</a>';
    } else {
      $nevent .= '<img class="wp-post-image" src="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/node-summit-event-logo.png" alt="'. get_the_title().'"/>';
    }
    $nevent .= '<h2><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h2>';    

    $i++;
  endwhile;
```

The code works and shows my image and post titles, but i get an error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: post_ID in
>   /home/nodesummit/public_html/wp-content/plugins/rt-cpts/events.php on
>   line 671

Can a kind person please let me know what I'm missing?

Comment: You haven't defined `$post_ID` in your loop. You probably mean to use the provided WP_Post Object `$post->ID` or `get_the_ID()` function.

Comment: @howdy_mcgee.  I see what you mean.  I tried with $post->ID and it gave an error "Trying to get property of non-object"  Left it out entirely and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) internally uses the `global $post` to get the post ID. That is why the code works while you are getting errors. it's not required to pass the post ID to this function, so you can pass `null` to it.

But the error is because there is no defined `$post_ID` variable. If you want to get the post's ID, you should either use `global $post; $post->ID;`, or better use `get_the_ID()`.

Comment: This worked.  I left out "$post_id" all together and no errors.

Comment: If you are using this inside the loop of your WP_Query then why are you providing the Post ID parameter in functions. You don't need to do that.